# There is no going back!

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

I live my life on the top floor,
Yet still aiming to get from where I am to something more,
An upgrade if you will,
Just by climbing the hill,
For glory to my possessor!

I usually take baby steps after a big stride,
Part of a long chain I often abide,
I often need my companions support,
Yet alone I can become to close for comfort,
With a little shove!

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is:**

> A pawn in chess!

I live my life on the top floor,

> They are found on the second row of the chess board above the major pieces

Yet still aiming to get from where I am to something more,

> Reach the top row to become a queen

An upgrade if you will,

> become a queen

Just by climbing the hill,

> moving upwards

For glory to my possessor!

> to win the game

I usually take baby steps after a big stride,

> moving one square forward at a time after pushing two squares forward.

Part of a long chain I often abide,

> usually found in a pawn chain

I often need my companions support,

> other pawns that support, part of a chain, or other pieces

Yet alone I can become to close for comfort,

With a little shove!

> It can attack enemies’ pieces with a push.

Title

> Pawns cannot move backwards

What am I?

> A Chess pawn

Comment: Hey firephil welcome to PSE you got the right answer but I would like a more thorough explanation of the riddle line for line before I can accept it. And the title too please.

Comment: It is ok difficulty i guess